# How do I extend variable labels in a column throughout an entire data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have data and I would like to have the gender and age groups expand throughout the entire dataset. Below is what the current data looks like, and then what it would ideally look like:

Current:

```
gender  variable   age  
1       
    18-24 variabl1  0.6
          variable2 0.3
    25-39 variable1 0.1
          variable2 0.3
    40-50 variable1 0.1
          variable2 0.30
2       
    18-24 variabl1  0.6
          variable2 0.3
    25-39 variable1 0.1
          variable2 0.3
    40-50 variable1 0.1
          variable2 0.30
```

NOTE: I don't want to change the physical structure of the data frame (i.e. rearranging columns and rows)

I've done quite a bit of Googling, but unfortunately, I haven't found anything too helpful.

to get where I currently am, I have simply completed a replacement of males and females and then a groupby:

```
data['gender'].replace(['Male', 'Female'],[1,2], inplace=True)
df = data.groupby(['gender', 'age'])["variable"].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Ideal:

```
   gender   variable   age  
    1       
    1   18-24 variabl1  0.6
    1   18-24 variable2 0.3
    1   25-39 variable1 0.1
    1   25-39 variable2 0.3
    1   40-50 variable1 0.1
    1   40-50 variable2 0.30
    2       
    2   18-24 variabl1  0.6
    2   18-24 variable2 0.3
    2   25-39 variable1 0.1
    2   25-39 variable2 0.3
    2   40-50 variable1 0.1
    2   40-50 variable2 0.30
```

Comment: @rafaelc Sorry, I'm new to Pandas and Python. Are you able to elaborate with an example please?

Comment: I get the error - "ValueError: cannot insert 'variable', already exists"

Comment: does the error make more sense now that I've edited the above code?

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-36a859aed271> in <module>
----> 1 df.head().to_dic()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5065             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5066                 return self[name]
-> 5067             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5068 
   5069     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_dic'

Comment: Can you add replicable example starting from the raw data so that we can replicate your problem?

Comment: Here is a link to the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vtL6twXVC-YgZiyV2TdQiYYnwTxUqwCEKqDIY7TIV0E/edit?usp=sharing

I have just copied it from the desktop xlsx file to a GoogleSheet

and here is the code that got me here:

filepath = c drive something

data = pd.read_excel(open(filepath,'rb'),sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
data['gender'].replace(['Male', 'Female'],[1,2], inplace=True)

df = data.groupby(['gender', 'age'])['talent_prompted__Johnny'].value_counts(normalize=True)

df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work I believe. The problem is that there is a name conflict when you reset the index. You need to rename the column for number to something else. I renamed it to 'value' here.

```
df.rename('value').reset_index()

    gender      age talent_prompted__Johnny     value
0        1  "18-24"              response 1  0.621622
1        1  "18-24"           I do not know  0.216216
2        1  "18-24"              response 5  0.081081
3        1  "18-24"              response 2  0.027027
4        1  "18-24"              response 4  0.027027
..     ...      ...                     ...       ...
74       2  "50-54"              response 2  0.027027
75       2  "50-54"              response 5  0.027027
76       2  "55-59"              response 1  0.694444
77       2  "55-59"           I do not know  0.194444
78       2  "55-59"              response 7  0.111111

[79 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Also, not sure if i have to create an entirely new thread, but if I wanted to include a second column in the original analysis, how would I do it?? Would it just be included in this line?? (i.e. want to include 'talent_prompted__cindy'  - as well)

df = data.groupby(['gender', 'age'])['talent_prompted__Johnny'].value_counts(normalize=True)

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way do multiple variables at once. You might want to write a for loop, repeat the whole process for each variable and then join the  result together.